# Error with MySQL syntax in java

Tags: java, mysql

```
PreparedStatement sql1 = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE `bantable` " +
        "SET reason=?, admin=?, started=?, time=?, ends=?, banned=?, datetimes=? " +
        "WHERE DATE_SUB(`datetimes`, NOW())<=0 AND player=?;");
```

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in
    your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
    version for the right syntax to use near 'NOW())<=0 AND player='Juustoast''
    at line 1
```

Why does it print that error?

Comment: First of all, be consistent with your `\``. Don't just use them when you feel like. Also, [`NOW()` is not an `INTERVAL`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW()` is just a datetime, so if `datetimes` also is you can just compare them using normal operators

```
WHERE datetimes < NOW()
```

If `datetimes` is *not* a `datetime`, `date`, or `timestamp` you will have to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

[`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is not a time interval, so you couldn't apply [`DATE_SUB`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) to it. Use solution proposed in the [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102198/274205).